# How to get instance of service from Instrumentation class?

Tags: android, automated-tests, integration-testing

I try to write an integration class for my bussiness logic. What I have done:
Start an activity,
Perform click that start another activity and a service that send commands to the server,
Get an instance of the second activity and after some time perform stop that ends all work - activity and service

The success of test I distinguish if content provider doesn't have any data, but it is not enough. I need to check what service return when I have sent command. The issue is the service has a instance of class that receive responses from server and I don't known how to get the service from my test case.

```
class MyTestCase extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    public void testMethos() {
                Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();

    Log.i(TAG, "Try to add monitor");
    ActivityMonitor monitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(
            MyActivity.class.getName(), 
            null, false);
     final DriverActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) 
        instrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, 5);
}
}
```

So in this case I can reach the activity that is run now but this approach suitiable only for Activity not For Services. If I'm be able obtain a service I will get my inner instance of class which responseible to handle reponses from server  - I going to do that via reflection.

Bu main question how I can obtain a service instance from my test case?